# assign the result of find to a array

Tags: bash, shellcheck

I am wondering if there is a better way in bash when passing an array of values to a program like zip since shell check complains like shown in the example.
First call shows a way which works but shell check complains, second zip does not work but shell check is happy.

After this question was closed since I guess oversimplified the example an tried a few thing using the lings supplied and came up with this solution. I added brackets around the call of find and added declare -a. Now both zip calls work.

Is that the correct way of solving this problem?

What is the preferred way to solve this in bash?

```
#!/bin/bash

touch file1.txt
touch file2.txt

declare -a filenames=($(find . -name "file*.txt"))
zip_filename="myzip.zip"

#works but shell check complians https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2068
zip -v -j "works_${zip_filename}" ${filenames[@]}

#does not work
zip -v -j "not_working_${zip_filename}" "${filenames[@]}"
```

Comment: `proto_filenames` is not an array

Comment: The assignment should have been like `proto_filenames=(file1 file2)` if you want `proto_filenames` to be an array.